# Whats the fastest, portable way to hash pointers we know are pointer aligned to a fixed size int?

Tags: c, hash

If we have a set of pointers we know are aligned to `sizeof(void *)` whats that fastest way to hash them?

Notes:

- Example use case is taking elements of a pointer array or memory allocations and storing in a hash-map. Noting this because this question isn't about the kind of cryptographic hashing needed for passwords, security etc.
- By fixed size int, I mean we know the exact size of the int and it wont vary *(perhaps this is important since some hashing libraries use `intptr_t` or `size_t` for their hashing return values which might give a different answer to this question).*
- By portable, this should work for 32, 64 bit, big & little endian.
- `(uint32_t)(((intptr_t)p) >> 2)` gives good results for 32bit, big endian, however I imagine it looses significant bits for 64bit systems, and I'm not sure if this gives a usable distribution for little endian.

Comment: So, the target is an `uint` (presumably `unsigned int`, and presumably 32-bit)?

Comment: @Deduplicator, yes, clarified.

Comment: This shouldn't be affected by endianness, as there is no reinterpretation of memory involved. The pointer just is the pointer either way, nothing funny would happen to it.

Comment: Maybe use a hashfunction? To fold back from 60bits to ~<32 bits? *anything goes* BTW: most shift&&xor hash functions are lower-bits-oblivious.

Answer (score 3):

When mod math is fast, a quick hash is to mod by a `prime <= TARGET_TYPE_MAX`.  The mod will use all the bits of the `p` to form the hash.

By using the largest prime, only a few buckets are lost, but speed is the goal.

Example, if the target tpye is `uint32_t`, use 4294967291u.

With variant sized integer types like `int`, use macros to select the precomputed prime.  [Primes just less than a power of two](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/2small/0bit.html).

```
#define LARGEST_PRIME8 251u
#define LARGEST_PRIME15 32749u
#define LARGEST_PRIME16 65521u
#define LARGEST_PRIME31 2147483647u
#define LARGEST_PRIME32 4294967291u
#define LARGEST_PRIME63 9223372036854775783u
#define LARGEST_PRIME64 18446744073709551557u

uint32_t hash = (uint32_t) ((uintptr_t)(void *)p) % LARGEST_PRIME32);
```

Comment: Two things, firstly, with pointer aligned values, this is guaranteed to give poor distribution (bit shift can solve of course). Second modulo operations are known to be slow, many C hashing libraries use bit-shifting instead (GTK's `GHashTable` for eg). Is there something about these sizes that allows them to be computed faster than a regular modulo?

Comment: @ideasman42 Any compiler worth its bits will do strength-reduction for division / modulo with known divisor.

Comment: @ideasman42 Disagree with "this is guaranteed to give poor distribution" - modding by a prime flattens distribution of items like pointers which tend to have clumped bit values.  As to "Second modulo operations are known to be slow" does not apply here as 1 this answer starts with the premise "When mod math is fast" and 2, good compilers are know to well optimize modulo based on fixed constant divisors..

Comment: If the pointers are aligned to 8 bytes for eg, then modulo by a large number will still leave gaps between the values, if the memory locations are from one region of memory (a larger array allocation for eg). As for modulo w/ a fixed size, I was aware the fixed value can be optimized out, but would still want to compare it with bit shifting and xor for eg.

Comment: @ideasman42 With a 64-bit pointer and mod 4294967291 to hash to a `uint32_t`, there are not large gaps.  Perhaps a numeric example to express your point abut _large gaps_.

Comment: Not large gaps, but being aligned to pointer size causes even, small gaps the size of a pointer. With this Python expression, these values are still 8 apart: `[i % 4294967291 for i in range(9223372036854775783, 9223372036854775783 + 100, 8)]` (9223372036854775783 is just an example of a large number standing in place for a 64bit memory address)

Comment: @ideasman42 True, the values remain 8 apart.  For a [cryptographic hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) that is bad, but OP specified "this question isn't about the kind of cryptographic hashing ".  Using the hash for a table look-up, having the hashes being usually different is sufficient.

Comment: The best would combine these 2.

Comment: Just a note: Primes one less than a power of two are known as [Mersenne primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime); and numbers that are one less than a power of two as Mersenne numbers.

Answer (score 3):

If you are okay creating a 64bit in -> 64 bit out restriction, the mumur3 hash finalizer function has very good properties.

Here's the 64 bit one (from discussion here: http://zimbry.blogspot.com/2011/09/better-bit-mixing-improving-on.html)

```
UInt64 MurmurHash3Mixer( UInt64 key )
{
  key ^= (key >> 33);
  key *= 0xff51afd7ed558ccd;
  key ^= (key >> 33);
  key *= 0xc4ceb9fe1a85ec53;
  key ^= (key >> 33);
  return key;
}
```

Some additional discussion about discovering such functions, including 32 bit -> 32bit variants. https://nullprogram.com/blog/2018/07/31/

Googling around with terms like "full avalanche" or "mumur3 mixing vs..." should get you a seemingly infinite amount of things to read.

one more link: [How to create a custom Murmur Avalanche Mixer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218741/how-to-create-a-custom-murmur-avalanche-mixer)